Finding Correspondence between Matrices after Decomposing a Hermitian Matrix
After decomposing the Hermitian matrix $M$, I obtain a set of matrices $D_j$, where each $D_j$ is defined as
$D_j = \lambda_j u_j u_j^H$,
$\lambda_j$ and $u_j$ are eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and $M$ is the sum of these matrices $M = \sum_j D_j$. I need to find the correspondence between $D_j$ and the columns of $M$. Is it possible to find this correspondence or introduce a parameter to facilitate it? Currently, I use the following parameter:
$p_{ij} = M_i \cdot D_{ji}$,
which is the scalar multiplication of i columns. I assume that the j-th eigenvalue corresponds to the i-th column with the maximal value of $p_{ij}$. However, this approach fails when $\lambda_j = 0$. Is it possible to introduce a projection operator? I would appreciate any information on this matter.
